# How to not open the plot in gnuplot script

Tags: gnuplot

I'd like to avoid the opening of the plot, just to export it to the eps format.
This code produce the eps file, but open a window during half a second

```
clear
reset
unset key
set xtics rotate out
set yrange [ 0 : 100 ]
set grid ytics linestyle 1
set style data histogram
# Give the bars a plain fill pattern, and draw a solid line around them.
set style fill solid border
set style histogram clustered
set boxwidth 0.9 absolute
set key inside right top vertical Right noreverse noenhanced autotitles nobox
set terminal postscript eps color
set output 'output.eps'
plot for [COL=1:2] 'test.dat' using COL:xticlabels(1) title columnheader ls COL
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clear` opens a plotting window. You don't need this since you plot to a file. Just remove it and you're fine.

Comment: Thank you... I would have never thought about this